# Kivy recycleview items get reordered when window gets resized

Tags: python, kivy

I use Kivy's `recycleview` to show a list of data in a table like manner. I used the [example from the docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html?highlight=recycleview#) as a base for my implementation.

In my program the RecycleDataView is based on a BoxLayout and its child widgets are generated dynamically.

This seems to work but the order in which the items are displayed is sometimes reversed and keeps changing if your resize the window. Even worse, if you scroll down, the layout gets completely crazy. This does not happen if I would use a simple label as item class, so I guess the problem is with my dynamicaly created widget logic but I don't understand why.

Here is some minimal code that shows the issue.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

Builder.load_string('''

<RV>:
    viewclass: 'RVItem'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'

''')

class Attribute:
    def __init__(self, name, values):
        self.name = name
        self.values = values


class RVItem(RecycleDataViewBehavior, BoxLayout):
    index = None
    attribute = ObjectProperty()

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        self.create_widgets(data.pop('attribute', None))
        return super(RVItem, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def create_widgets(self, value: Attribute):
        """Dynamically create the needed Widgets"""

        if value is None:
            return
        self.add_widget(Label(text=value.name, height=self.height, size_hint=(1, None)))

        if not isinstance(value.values, dict):
            self.add_widget(Label(text=value.values, height=self.height, size_hint=(1, None)))
        else:
            for _, v in value.values.items():
                self.add_widget(Label(text=v, height=self.height, size_hint=(1, None)))

        image_button = Button(text='+')
        #image_button.source = 'wm_ui/glyphs/plus.png'
        image_button.size_hint = None, None
        image_button.size = "30sp", "30sp"
        image_button.bind(on_press=self.add_button_pressed)
        self.add_widget(image_button)

    def add_button_pressed(self, s):
        print("Would add a new item to the recycleview if implemented.")


class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'attribute': Attribute(str(x), "test")} for x in range(100)]


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

I changed some Widgets to their base classes for simplicity (like ImageButton and Label)

When you run the application you should see that the order if the items is reversed and starting with 10 instead of 100 for some reason.

[image: the started application]

After resizing the window with the mouse in one of the window's corners you should see the contents continuously reordering.

[image: after resizing the window a bit]

And if you scroll down, things get even more crazy.

[image: after scrolling down the list]

Unfortunately I have no idea what causes the behavior. I developed some Kivy apps before but this is my first really deep dive that uses more than just labels and a few inputs.

Comment: Is there a fixed maximum number of `Label` widgets that will appear in one `RVItem`?

Comment: @JohnAnderson I expect it to be not more than 10 but you never know what users might do. The number of labels is two at minimum but there is no defined maximum because it's depending on the number of values the user sets (defined in the Attribute class). Think of it as as the columns of a user defined table. I can't know how much widgets there will be beforehand.

Comment: The `RecyleView` is doing what it is expected to do, that is reusing your `RVItem` widgets. The problem is that your `refresh_view_attrs()` is adding more `Label` and `Button` widgets to those recycled `RVItems`. That is why as you scroll down, you see more and more `Label` and `Button` widgets in each `RVItem`. Since the `RVItems` are being recycled, your `refresh_view_attrs()` needs to set ALL the attributes for  an `RVItem` (including the `name`). Also, since your `refresh_view_attrs()` is creating all those widgets, you are not taking advantage of the `Recycle` part of `RecycleView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a modification of your code that seems to work correctly:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

Builder.load_string('''

<RV>:
    viewclass: 'RVItem'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'

''')

class Attribute:
    def __init__(self, name, values):
        self.name = name
        self.values = values


class RVItem(RecycleDataViewBehavior, BoxLayout):
    index = None
    attribute = ObjectProperty()

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        self.create_widgets(data['attribute'])
        return super(RVItem, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def create_widgets(self, value: Attribute):
        rv = App.get_running_app().root
        rv.cache_widgets(self.children)
        self.clear_widgets()
        label = rv.get_label()
        label.text = value.name
        self.add_widget(label)
        if isinstance(value.values, dict):
            for _,v in value.values.items():
                label = rv.get_label()
                label.text = v
                self.add_widget(label)
        else:
            label = rv.get_label()
            label.text = value.values
            self.add_widget(label)
        image_button = rv.get_button()
        image_button.text = '+'
        image_button.size_hint = None, None
        image_button.size = "30sp", "30sp"
        image_button.bind(on_press=self.add_button_pressed)
        self.add_widget(image_button)


    def add_button_pressed(self, s):
        print("Would add a new item to the recycleview if implemented.")


class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.label_cache = []
        self.button_cache = []
        self.data = [{'attribute': Attribute(str(x), "test")} for x in range(100)]
        for i in range(100):
            if i % 5 == 0:
                self.data[i]['attribute'].values = {'1': 'test1', '2': 'test2', '3': 'test3'}

    def get_button(self):
        if len(self.button_cache) > 0:
            return self.button_cache.pop()
        else:
            return Button()

    def get_label(self):
        if len(self.label_cache) > 0:
            return self.label_cache.pop()
        else:
            return Label()

    def cache_widgets(self, widgets):
        for w in widgets:
            if isinstance(w, Button):
                self.button_cache.append(w)
            else:
                self.label_cache.append(w)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

In this version, the `refresh_view_attrs` method always sets all the attributes of the `RVItem`. The line

```
self.create_widgets(data.pop('attribute', None))
```

is replaced with

```
self.create_widgets(data['attribute'])
```

because the `pop()` actually removes data, which I don't think you want to do.

The `RV` class now has a cache for `Label` widgets and another for `Button` widgets, and they get recycled (similar to what the `RecycleView` does. The `create_widgets` method removes all the children of the `RVItem` and adds them to the cache, then recycles or creates widgets, as needed, to fill out the `RVItem`.

I have added additional items to the `values` dict for some of the data, to help illustrate how this works.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I had the wrong Idea about how the recycling part works. Would you recommend that I use a factory and dynamically create the viewclasses with a fixed number of widgets instead?

Comment: If the created `RVItem` always has the same number of children, then the entire `RVItem` can be recycled by `RecycleView`, and the `refresh_view_attrs()` method can simply set the atributes of the `RVItem`. So, if a fixed number of children is possible for you, that would make it simpler.